# Change / Remove a file name just knowing the first 3 initials. (CMD / VBS)

Tags: vbscript, cmd, delete-file

My question is if there are any ways I can create a `CMD` or `VBS` script that can recognize a couple of file names just knowing the first 3 letters or numbers. Then removing the files and replacing them with my other files.

> Example: I have two files called MSO0127 and MSO1053. I want the my CMD or VBS-Script to recognize the word "MSO" and remove all files that starts with that.

Is it possible? If you have some solution for it using something else than CMD or VBS-Script, then please tell me!

I am also quite new to coding, which results in me not being very good understanding all the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because attempts at pranks are not welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html).

---

**From a command line**

To delete matching files:

```
del MSO*.*
```

Use the `/s` option to match files in subdirectories as well as the current directory.

---